# plyr equivalent of statement done using mapply

Tags: r, plyr

I'm guessing mlply should be used here for the equivalent of what I'm doing in mapply, but I'm not able to figure out how. I really would like to understand the plyr package better.

```
df <- data.frame(start=as.Date(c("2012-01-01","2012-02-02")),end=as.Date(c("2012-01-04","2012-02-08")))
l <- mapply(function(x,y) seq(x,y,by="day"),df$start, df$end)
```

Thanks in advance,
--JT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the big difference if that you need to name your function arguments in line with the variable names in your data frame:

```
mlply(df,function(start,end){seq(start,end,by = "day")})
```

Comment: this works too: dlply(df, .(start, end), function(ddf) seq(ddf$start,ddf$end,by="day"))